# Word meaning doing something wrong without realizing it

Tags: single-word-requests

So I'm pretty sure I know this but my mind has gone blank and when I think I've found the word it disappears from my mind. I've tried to google it but it says nothing.

I need to know the word for unintentionally doing something wrong without realizing it. I'm writing a story (don't judge) and here is the line that I need the word for:

> He goes to wipe my face but I move back. In a flash his eyes were blazed with fury. He raised his hand and slapped me harshly round my face. My eyes were wide with fear and I started to shake as he unleashed his fury onto me. "DON'T YOU EVER ...'

It's up to there that i cant figure it out.

Please help people :))

Comment: It doesn't make too much sense that the other person is using the word you're looking for. Why would they be so angry if they know you're unaware of your transgression? You might have *inadvertently* not known it was wrong, but they seem to think you were complicit in the wrongdoing.

Comment: The context given makes this ambiguous; do you mean wrong in a *moral* sense ("I shouldn't have done that") or in the *competence* sense ("I tried, but I failed")?

Comment: Why not mistakenly?

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with, as based on John's comment and what you're trying to convey, is this:

> He goes to wipe my face but I (*inadvertently*) move back (*in error*). In a flash his eyes were blazed with fury. He raised his hand and slapped me harshly round my face. My eyes were wide with fear and I started to shake as he unleashed his fury onto me. "DON'T YOU EVER (*PULL AWAY FROM ME*)...'

The suggestion is to place the description of this action in the sentence in which your character moves away from the aggressor, as it is not known to the aggressor that the action your character commits is unintentionally a mistake, but rather is likely seeing it as a deliberate action (possibly of defiance).

But, well, you're the author :)

Answer (score 0):

As the first idea I would suggest **blunder**. From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blunder%22MerriamWebster%22) dictionary:

> to make a mistake through stupidity, ignorance, or carelessness

Don't you ever **blunder**?

Answer (score 0):

**goof-up**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/goof-up)

> a mistake, blunder, or malfunction.

As in:

> Don't you ever goof-up?

Answer (score -1):

I suspect what you are getting into is either one of these forms...

> **Act unconsciously.**
>
> **On a whim.**

There are plethora words for a similar context, but those two came to my head the first.

Comment: Neither of these capture the aspect of doing something wrong, and the second one doesn't capture the aspect of doing something without realizing it.

Comment: I doubt a person would be to do anything GREAT while unconscious. And you should double-check what the meaning of **whim** is. These words are alright and suitable, considering that he is not writing a creative commons document.

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please.